# Regex result contains extra match/group with just a return

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I would like to match everything between **start** and **end** given the following string:

```
const test = `this is the start
a
b
c
e
f
end
g
h
`;
```

I have the following regex

```
const output = test.match(/start((.|\n)*)end/m);
```

No, `output[0]` contains the whole string that matched (with start and end)
`output[1]` is the match (everything between start and end)
`output[2]` is only a return (\n)

[DEMO](https://playcode.io/1806962)

[image]

What I don't understand is where does the second match/group (output[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTunN.png)) come from. Amy suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your regular expression: `((.|\n)*)` creates two capturing groups. The outer group collects all the matched "anything" characters matched by the inner `*` group. The inner group will contain the last matched single character.

Note that you'd probably be better off with a slightly different regular expression to avoid the odd effect of collecting too many characters in the groups before backtracking takes over.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Now I was able to fix it as follows: **/start((?:.|\n)*)end/m**

Answer (score 2):

As Pointy mentioned, you have two capturing groups.

If you use a named capturing group, this makes the code easier to write and understand:

```js
const test = `this is the start
a
b
c
e
f
end
g
h
`;

console.log(test.match(/start(?<between>(.|\n)*)end/m).groups.between)
```

Comment: "Named Capturing Groups" is new for me. Appreciate you bringing it up!

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have described I would assume you want to match from 'start' to 'end', but your example is not quite doing that. So I am providing two examples you can chose from depending what you might need.

1. Match from 'start' to first 'end' the ? makes the [\s\S]+ non greedy.

```
/(?<=start)[\s\S]+?(?=end)/
```

```js
const test = `this is the start
a
b
c
e
f
end
g
end
h
`;

console.log(test.match(/(?<=start)[\s\S]+?(?=end)/))
```

2. Match from 'start' to last 'end' greedy - keep going till last is matched.

```
/(?<=start)[\s\S]+(?=end)/
```

```js
const test = `this is the start
a
b
c
e
f
end
g
end
h
`;

console.log(test.match(/(?<=start)[\s\S]+(?=end)/))
```

I am using [\s\S] which means any Whitespace or Non Whitespace character essentially what you had with (.|\n) but takes care of more scenarios.

I am also using Lookahead and Lookbehind which is now widely supported in JS, so that the match is in 0 position of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Your second capture group matches a newline, because repeating a capture group captures the value of the last iteration.

The last iteration of `(.|\n)*` is the newline after the `f` char and before `end`

**Notes**

- The `*` is greedy and will first match all characters first, then it will backtrack to the first occurrence of `end`
- You don't need the `/m` flag for multiline as the pattern has no anchors
- If you don't want partial word matches you can use word boundaries like `\bstart\b` and `\bend\b`
- If you want multiple matches, you can specify the `/g` for global matches and make the quantifier non greedy `[^]*?`
- The pattern `(.|\n)*` is very inefficient as you are optionally repeating a single character or a newline, leaving a lot of paths to backtrack into

You can use a single capture group, and in Javascript you can write the pattern as:

```
start([^]*)end
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u9cI4n/1)

```js
const regex = /start([^]*)end/;
const str = `this is the start
a
b
c
e
f
end
g
h`;

const m = str.match(regex);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```